# how to determine count and edit a random from the result?

Tags: php, preg-replace

this is my current php-script.

```
$mystr = 'Hello world. The world is nice';
substr_count($mystr, 'world'); // count=2;
$mytext = preg_replace('/\b('.$mystr.')\b/i', '<b>$1</b>', $mytext);
```

I want to have randomly one of the word in bold.
Is there any smart way?
Thx in advanced, Steven

Comment: Do you want one of the 'world' occurrence to be bold, or _any_ one word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to make a specific word, i.e. `world` bold? If yes, one way could be:

```
function make_bold($str, $replace) {
    $words = array_intersect(str_word_count(strtolower($str), 2), $replace);
    if(count($words) > 0) {
        $rand_pos = array_rand($words);
        $str = substr_replace($str, '<b>' . $words[$rand_pos] . '</b>', $rand_pos, strlen($words[$rand_pos]));
    }
    return $str;
}
```

used as:

```
$str = make_bold($str, array('world'));
```

---

**Reference:** [`str_word_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php), [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

Watch a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/DTyE7).

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystr = 'Hello world. The world is nice';
$words = explode(' ', $mystr);
$randWordKey = rand(0, count($words));
$words[$randWordKey] = '<b>' . $words[$randWordKey] . '</b>';
$mytext = implode(' ', $words);
```